# ImportError: libopencv_hdf.so.3.3

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04. to 18.04. When I now try to import cv2 in python I receive the message:

ImportError: libopencv_hdf.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So reinstalled opencv (version 3.4) by following these instructions: https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/804a663b449e4cdb31b5fea96bb9d561

Installation worked fined, but I still receive the error message. I need help, please. Let me know what kind of code you need and I try to list it below.

Regards

Comment: What's your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: how are you importing cv2?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. After import sys, I typed for p in sys.path:, and then typed print(p). This shows quite a few Pythonpaths. Most of them are under /usr/lib/python2.7. The funny thing is that python tries to grab the older opencv version 3.3. But I removed this version and I installed version 3.4. When I create a symbolic link with the old name and the new lib file, import cv2 does not recognise it as a problem any more. But then it asks for the next libopencv**.3.3 file.

Comment: @DejanMarić import cv2